# React - Strange fatal error in some browsers

Tags: reactjs, cross-browser, runtime-error, react-router, flux

Question about a strange error, which occurs only in certain browsers.

I have a huge single page application similar to a file storage with files and folders. This application is build on react and flux and i use react-router for routing.

In some browsers, I found a critical error, and I can not find the right solution.

The problem is that when I try to download the files in a folder, get the following error:

```
Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.
```

and thereafter

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Attempted to update component `Header` that has already been unmounted (or failed to mount).
```

'Header' - one of the components of the application.

The strange thing is that this error occurs only in some versions of Chrome and Firefox. I think problem is in first error.

This is my webpack config:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname + '/src',
    entry: {
        index: './index'
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/public',
        publicPath: "/public",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },

    watch: NODE_ENV == 'development',
    watchOptions: {
        aggregateTimeout: 100
    },

    resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: ["node_modules"],
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },

    resolveLoader: {
        modulesDirectories: ["node_modules"],
        moduleTemplates: ["*-loader", "*"],
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },

    plugins: [

    ],

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js|jsx$/,
                loader: "babel",
                exclude: [/node_modules/],
                query: {
                    plugins: ['transform-runtime'],
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    };

if(NODE_ENV == 'production') {
        module.exports.plugins.push(
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
                compress: {
                    warnings: false,
                    drop_console: true,
                    unsafe: true
                }
            })
        );
}
```

And my package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.13.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.12.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.13.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.13.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.11.6",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1"
},
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.14.0",
    "choices.js": "^2.0.2",
    "events": "^1.1.1",
    "flux": "^2.1.1",
    "keymirror": "^0.1.1",
    "react": "^15.3.0",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.3.1",
    "react-alert": "^1.0.14",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.0",
    "react-dotdotdot": "^1.0.16",
    "react-image-lightbox": "^3.1.0",
    "react-mixin": "^3.0.5",
    "react-modal": "^1.4.0",
    "react-player": "^0.9.0",
    "react-router": "^2.6.1"
  }
```

Does anyone have any idea what any of this?
Because of what the problem may be?